# pyspark - iterating through the file and substituting the value in dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql

I need to read through the file and substitute the value while the s3 path.I am able to loop through the file but I am not able to substitute the value.

```
File ending with \n
/MTD_avg_cust_bal1
/MTDSumOfCustomerInitiatedTrxns1
/MTDCountOfCustomerInitiatedTrxns1
```

**Code:**

```
metrics = open("Output.txt","r")
line = metrics.readline()

while line:
    print line
    line = metrics.readline()
    s3path = ("SELECT * FROM parquet.`s3n://bucket{}/loaddate=20170406/part-r-00000-d60b633d-ff49-4515-8cff-ace9faf1b267.csv`") .format(line).strip('\n')

    print s3path
    df1 = sqlContext.sql(s3path)
```

**Error:**

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'Path does not exist: s3n://omniscience1/MTDSumOfCustomerInitiatedTrxns1\n/loaddate=20170406/part-r-00000-d60b633d-ff49-4515-8cff-ace9faf1b267.csv;; line 1 pos 14'
```

The problem is it's including `\n` when the value is substituted and also I need to have separate data frame for each line.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you can let us know how your output should look like.

I'm not a python expert. But below is what I've come up with based on my understanding. Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

```
with open("Output.txt", 'r') as file:

    for line in file:
        line = line.strip('\n')
        s3path = ("SELECT * FROM parquet.`s3n://bucket{}/loaddate=20170406/part-r-00000-d60b633d-ff49-4515-8cff-ace9faf1b267.csv`") .format(line)

        print (s3path)
```

The output of the above script is below.

```
SELECT * FROM parquet.`s3n://bucket/MTD_avg_cust_bal1/loaddate=20170406/part-r-00000-d60b633d-ff49-4515-8cff-ace9faf1b267.csv`
SELECT * FROM parquet.`s3n://bucket/MTDSumOfCustomerInitiatedTrxns1/loaddate=20170406/part-r-00000-d60b633d-ff49-4515-8cff-ace9faf1b267.csv`
SELECT * FROM parquet.`s3n://bucket/MTDCountOfCustomerInitiatedTrxns1/loaddate=20170406/part-r-00000-d60b633d-ff49-4515-8cff-ace9faf1b267.csv`
```

Comment: Yes , it should be like  df1=SELECT * FROM parquet.`s3n://bucket/MTD_avg_cust_bal1/loaddate=20170406/part-r-00000-d60b633d-ff49-4515-8cff-ace9faf1b267.csv`

Comment: Are you planning to generate data frame names (like df1, df2) on the fly? If so, may I know a little bit more why you are doing this?

Comment: Thanks Raju for the input , I am able to read the file , but its reading only the last line of the file . Yes I need to create dataframe on the fly and then join them

Comment: with open("Output.txt","r") as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip('\n')     s3path = "SELECT * FROM parquet.`s3n://omniscience1{}/loaddate=20170406/part*.parquet`" .format(line) df=sqlContext.sql(s3path)